# R - ggplot showing distribution of binary flag variable (0/1) over time as normalized bar chart (%)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set looking sth like this ....

```
Date        Remaining  Volume   ID
1990-01-01  0          1000     1
1990-01-01  1          2000     2
1990-01-01  1          5000     3
1990-02-01  0          200      4
1990-03-01  1          4000     5
1990-03-01  0          3000     6
```

I filter the data according to a series of conditional statements and assign the binary flag variable to the data.table. A value of `0` means that the particular row entry doesn't meet the defined requirements and will subsequently be excluded; `1`-flagged rows remain in the data.table. The key is `ID` and is unique for each row.

I would like to show two relationships.

**(1)** A stacked normalized/percentage bar chart over the monthly time series to show the *percentage of entries remaining/being excluded* in the data.set for each month,

f.ex. Jan 1990 --> 2/3 values remaining --> **66.6% vs. 33.3% of entries remain vs. are excluded**

**(2)** A stacked normalized/percentage bar chart showing the normalized *percentage of volume remaining/ being excluded* by the filtering operation for each month,

f.ex. Jan 1990 --> 2k + 5k out of 8k remaining --> **87.5% vs. 12.5%  of volume remains vs. is excluded**

I tried various things so far, f.ex. compute the number of occurences of each flag-value per month and the sum of the corresponding "bucket" (0/1) volume, but all my attempts failed so far.

```
# dt_1 is the original data.table
id.vec <- dt_1[ , id]
dt_2 <- dt_1
# dt_1 is filterd subsequently
id_remaining.vec <- dt_1[ , id]

dt_2 <- dt_2[id.vec %in% id_remaining.vec, REMAIN := 1]
dt_2 <- dt_2[id.vec %notin% id_remaining.vec, REMAIN := 0]
dt_2 <- dt_2[REMAIN == 1 , N_REMAIN := .N]
dt_2 <- dt_2[REMAIN == 1 , N_REMAIN_MON := .N]

# Tried the code below to no avail
ggplot(data = dt_2, aes(x = Date, y = REMAIN, color = REMAIN, fill = REMAIN)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity")
```

Usually, I find ggplot grammar very intuitive, but I guess I am overlooking sth here or maybe the data set is not in the right format.

Any pointer or idea highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dt_2 %>%
  mutate(Remaining = as.character(Remaining)) %>%  # just to make the charts use scale_fill_discrete by default
  group_by(Date, Remaining) %>%
  summarize(entries = n(),
         volume = sum(Volume)) %>%
  mutate(share_entries = entries / sum(entries),
            share_volume = volume / sum(volume)) %>%
  ungroup() -> dt_2_summary

> dt_2_summary
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  Date       Remaining entries volume share_entries share_volume
  <chr>      <chr>       <int>  <int>         <dbl>        <dbl>
1 1990-01-01 0               1   1000         0.333        0.125
2 1990-01-01 1               2   7000         0.667        0.875
3 1990-02-01 0               1    200         1            1    
4 1990-03-01 0               1   3000         0.5          0.429
5 1990-03-01 1               1   4000         0.5          0.571
```

Then to chart:

```
dt_2_summary %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, share_entries, fill = Remaining)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

```
dt_2_summary %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, share_volume, fill = Remaining)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: That it awesome John! I love your proposed solution in particular as the ```ggplot()``` calls are so compact as a result of the data wrangling beforehand. Your answer is exactly what I was hoping for and more! **Very much appreciated!**

One short follow-up question though. Why do you have to change the ```integer``` column ```Remain``` to ```character```
 before grouping and summarizing?

Comment: I tried several versions now, but it took me a lot of time to debug on my end as I was getting a couple weird results before it finanally worked! 

And btw sorry for misspelling your name earlier Jon :)

Comment: I switched Remain to character only so that it would be a discrete variable going into ggplot. Otherwise it plots the 0's and 1's on a continuous scale and that seemed the quickest way around it.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Usually I just use ```as.factor(xyz)``` in the ```aes()``` mapping definition of the variable I want to use for coloring / filling my ```geom```.

But your way is quite elegant as well. Thanks again Jon!

In the end this was essentially just the backbone of my plot, that I further customized (date labels, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Just as an appendix to Jon's great soution.

I had a large project with >25 libraries loaded and while the proposed code seemingly worked, it only did work for the share_entries and not for share_volume. Output of `dt_2_summary` was weird. The share_entries column was apparently computed to the total number of entries and not within each group and the share_volume column only showed `NAs`.

After hours of troubleshooting, I identified the culprit to be the pkg `plyr`, which did overwrite some functions. Thus, I had to specify which version of the applied functions I wanted to use.

The code below did the trick for me.

```
library(plyr) # the culprit
library(dplyr)
dt_2 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Remaining = as.character(Remaining)) %>%
  group_by(Date, Remaining) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(entries = n(),
         volume = sum(Volume)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(share_entries = entries / sum(entries),
            share_volume = volume / sum(volume)) %>%
  ungroup() -> dt_2_summary
```

Thanks again Jon for your wonderful solutiopn!